# Git Installation is failing on Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

While trying to install the GIT plugin , it is keep on failing.

```
    java.io.IOException: Failed to download from http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/git-client/1.21.0/git-client.hpi
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:781)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1125)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1285)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1103)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:104)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to load http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/git-client/1.21.0/git-client.hpi to /home/jenkins/jenkins/plugins/git-client.jpi.tmp
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:766)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:134)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3053)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3047)
    at org.apache.commons.io.input.ProxyInputStream.read(ProxyInputStream.java:77)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:761)
```

I even tried to download the .hpi files for Git plugin and Git Client Plugin and upload it. It is throwing the below error.

```
 java.io.IOException: Failed to dynamically deploy this plugin
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1304)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1103)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:104)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to install git-client plugin
    at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:436)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1300)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Dependency structs (1.3) doesn't exist
    at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:488)
    at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:426)
    ... 6 more
```

Not able to find the dependent structs file. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error looks like you have problems with connectivity to the Jenkins update server, maybe due to firewall issues:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to load http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/git-client/1.21.0/git-client.hpi to /home/jenkins/jenkins/plugins/git-client.jpi.tmp
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:766)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
```

When you tried to install the .hpi file directly, you ran into a missing plugin dependency:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Dependency structs (1.3) doesn't exist
```

This is annoying because if you install from the update center, Jenkins will automatically install dependencies for you.  You could try downloading the .hpi for the structs plugin but you may then find more missing dependencies.

Comment: I did the workaround by downloading all the dependent plugins like structs, junit, git client, script-security,matrix-project etc.  But my concern is how to overcome this.

Comment: It will be good, if you can provide the steps or some suggestions for resolving the connectivity problem of Jenkins Update server.

Comment: Initially you could just try accessing the update center URL in a browser.  I've seen a couple of other questions on SO that suggest the site may have been down for a time.

Answer (score 0):

Download structs.hpi here:
http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/structs/1.3/structs.hpi
and upload manually using pluginManager - advanced,
restart the jenkins server, and check the log again or check on the installed plugin pluginManager - installed